# Correct class to intercept to change event background color

Tags: fullcalendar

I've updated from Fullcalendar from 1.6.4 to 3.0 (upgrading to 3.9 requires me to update to jQuery 3.x)

Before the background color was set at the `eventRender` event using the following code

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    if (event.stato == '1') {
        element.find('.fc-event-inner').addClass('redEvent');
    } else if (event.stato == '0') {
        element.find('.fc-event-inner').addClass('greyEvent');
    } else if (event.stato == '2') {
        element.find('.fc-event-inner').addClass('yellowEvent');
    } else if (event.stato == '3') {
        element.find('.fc-event-inner').addClass('greenEvent');
    }

    element.parent().find('.fc-event').removeClass('fc-event');
}
```

Now after having updated to 3.0 it seems that the CSS class `fc-event-inner` is not used anymore, what I've found is

```
 <td class="fc-event-container" colspan="3">
    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable">
        <div class="fc-content">
            <span class="fc-title">Long Event</span>
        </div>
        <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
    </a>
</td>
```

What shoud I use? I've tried with `fc-content` but a small white border on the right appears

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Have you tried calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent',calEvent);
 color: '#257e4a'?

Comment: I ve managed right Now... it's fullcalendar.print.css that causes troubles... removing it all is ok...